# Real-time ASR with Google API

Tags: architecture, api

I have a general question about the implementation of the ASR (automatic speech recognition) API of Google or a similar company.

We need to create clients (desktop applications) that send the microphone audio to the API and get the transcription back for further analysis. Please, note that we are talking of real-time (continuous) transcription (not audio files). The available APIs have a lot of documentation on how to implement it, in different languages (Python, etc.).

The basic question we have is: what is normal practice, 1) "client -> our server -> API to ASR provider -> our server -> client" or 2) "client -> API to server provider -> client"?

We have the impression that all examples offered for the APIs are of the 2) group. But if this is the case, how do people manage/hide the API keys (which are not public of course and you have to pay for)? Directly in the client code?!?

Probably it is a very stupid question, but I would be grateful for some feedback and ideas from real-life applications.

Comment: The server of your system can at the same time be the client of the ASR service, so 1 is not a problem. Then it depends on the kind of your application. For example, if you develop an android app, it's common to use the android APIs basically letting the operating system choose what to do (it can perform the recognition offline or use remote services).

Comment: Thank you Davide. 1) is okay, it implies however a step more (sending audio from client to server) which is a layer more of programming. But probably the right way to go. We develop for Desktop (Windows and macOS), no knowledge of any API for ASR of the OS.

Comment: In Windows, if you use the Universal Window Platform you can access these APIs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/speech-interactions, and I suppose that on macOS you can do something similar accessing siri apis.